# Changing href attribute doesn't work in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I would like to change `href` using jQuery Mobile, I tried a some code examples like:

```
$("a[href='http://www.google.com/']").attr('href', 'http://www.live.com/');
```

```
<li><a data-ajax="false" href="http://www.google.com" >Navigate</a></li>
```

and

```
$("#address").append("href", "http://cupcream.com");
```

```
<li><a data-ajax="false" id="address" href="http://www.google.com" >Navigate</a></li>
```

But nothing happens.

What can be wrong, aren't this some bug in jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to your "a" element the attribute `rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"`, in order for the links to not be managed via Ajax.
Official Documentation [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html).

Also look at 
[JQuery Mobile History on data-ajax=false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408453/jquery-mobile-history-on-data-ajax-false)

Answer (score 1):

Changing just `href` attibute did not work for me. I had to change both, text and the attribute `href` and that worked just fine. Tested on Chrome, Firefox and IE10.

```
$('#campuslink').text('http://www.google.com');

$('#campuslink').attr('href','http://www.google.com');
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have the `data-ajax="false"` then the link will not be changeable via the jquery attr function.  I see that you have it, but I'm mentioning it for future searches.

Once you have that, you can change the link like so: 
$('a[href='http://www.google.com/']').attr('href', 'http://www.live.com/');

I suggest ensuring that your selector is working as expected by doing a 'hide()' on a test case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.attr()` method, not `.append()`

```
$("#address").attr("href", "http://cupcream.com");
```