# JQuery Mobile History on data-ajax=false

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In building a mobile site using JQMobile. Due to the size of the project I decided to go to a multi-page approach (multiple html files). However, one of the pages I'm building makes more sense as a html file with multiple divs. In order to load these multiple divs I am forced to use either `rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"` so that it pulls all the div's with `data-role="page"` and not just the first div on the page. However, this breaks the JQMobile's history and no longer displays a back button when using `data-add-back-btn="true"`.

Does anybody know of a solution to pull multiple div's without forcing a full reload of the page? Or of a way to mix both paradigms yet conserve the history on JQMobile?

Comment: version of jQM you're using? maybe some code to how you're implementing it oh jsfiddle.net

Comment: I am using JQM 1.0b3. In addition, although I added this to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfpN8/2/), but it is hard since I have multiple html files. The problem is that the ajax methods only pulls the first div with `data-role="page"` yet I need one of this external html pages to have mutiple divs but when I do that, the back button is not rendered.

Comment: In the external page you need to add this to the navbar/header or whatever you/re using for navigation http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html data-add-back-btn="true" and/or data-rel="back"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/bfpN8/12/
- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/bfpN8/14/ (with back navigation)

Main HTML

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Demo Page</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque semper feugiat condimentum. Donec rutrum lectus tortor, et pharetra sapien. Sed sollicitudin lectus sed urna consectetur sagittis. Pellentesque at arcu dui. Curabitur molestie velit id neque mattis vestibulum. Sed sit amet ante at tellus volutpat tempor quis eu magna. Pellentesque elementum semper congue. Praesent vitae eros id ante dapibus commodo. Aliquam leo nisi, feugiat eu imperdiet sed, tincidunt in lacus. Praesent bibendum dapibus vestibulum. Fusce condimentum bibendum libero eu aliquet.</p>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-dividertheme="d" style="margin-top: 0;">
            <li><a href="http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/rGacN/4/embedded/result/" rel="external" data-transidiont="slide">Link 1 (External)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#internal">Internal Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#internal2">Internal Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#internal3">Internal Link3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

External HTML

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a data-rel="back">Back</a> <!-- Here you add the data-rel -->
        <h1>External Demo Page</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque semper feugiat condimentum. Donec rutrum lectus tortor, et pharetra sapien. Sed sollicitudin lectus sed urna consectetur sagittis. Pellentesque at arcu dui. Curabitur molestie velit id neque mattis vestibulum. Sed sit amet ante at tellus volutpat tempor quis eu magna. Pellentesque elementum semper congue. Praesent vitae eros id ante dapibus commodo. Aliquam leo nisi, feugiat eu imperdiet sed, tincidunt in lacus. Praesent bibendum dapibus vestibulum. Fusce condimentum bibendum libero eu aliquet.</p>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: Thank you for your example; the problem I am now hitting is that when I hit back from the external page, the back button on the previous page no longer appears. Let me explain with a scenario:

By the time I hit this page with the link `rel="external"` I have visited multiple "pages" and have generated a history since those pages have the `data-add-back-btn="true"` flag. However, after navigating to the external, and coming back, the back buttons are no longer present.

Comment: If you want to go back just add the data-rel attribute to each navigation/header page you need. I have added another example to show this. Navigate through all the pages, the last page is external as well: http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/bfpN8/14/